# Não consigo baixar as dependências do Hibernate e mysql #Algaworks

Tags: hibernate, jpa, maven

Estou acompanhando a apostila **`algaworks-ebook-java-ee-7-com-jsf-primefaces-e-cdi-2a-edicao-20150228`** e no projeto financeiro ao por as dependencias do **hibenate** e **mysql** no **pom xml** não consigo obter as bibliotecas e com isso não consigo fazer as anotações nas classes do modelo (Pessoa e Lancamento). 
Segue o meu arquivo **pom.xml**:

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.setup</groupId>
  <artifactId>Financeiro</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/antlr/antlr -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Núcleo do Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Implementação de EntityManager da JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Driver JDBC do MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Alguem ja enfretou um problema parecido e pudesse me dar uma dica?

Answer (score 0):

O que posso fazer para lhe ajudar é postar meu pom.xml. Dê uma olhada e veja se faltam dependencias como o CDI, e hibernate validator. Espero ter ajudado! Responda se deu certo.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.Rastrbov</groupId>
<artifactId>sisRastrbov</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>


<build>
    <finalName>sisRastrbov</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- núcleo do hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- implementação do Hibernate BeanValidator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>



    <!-- implementação do entityManager da Jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- weld - implementação do CDI -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Mojarra (implementação do JSF 2) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-m05</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Primefaces Biblioteca de componentes -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- TomEE <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId> <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId> 
        <version>6.0-6</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId> <artifactId>openejb-core</artifactId> 
        <version>4.7.4</version> </dependency> -->

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId> <artifactId>apache-tomee</artifactId> 
        <version>1.7.4</version> </dependency> -->

    <!-- cdi <dependency> <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId> <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId> 
        <version>1.2</version> </dependency> -->
</dependencies>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```